# ASP.NET WebForms File Upload with a progress bar

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, webforms, progress-bar

I am trying to accomplish a File Upload Progress Bar but can't find a right solution. There are many suggestions on the File Upload Progress Bar implementation out on the web but those suggestion seem to be chaotic and outdated

1. A lot of File Upload Progress Bar solutions implement IFrame, which is out of the questions because it will undermine the site's security
2. Some solutions suggest SignalR but the SignalR itself doesn't really deal with the upload itself
3. Some solutions suggest WebClient progress bar, but is it feasible to swap File Upload control code behind with the WebClient functionality in the classical ASP.NET just for the sake of progress bar?
4. There are a lot of suggestion to use HttpHandler, which will result in a substantial changes of our current architecture (plus it looks like we have to buy some JQuery (Uplodify) functionality.
5. There are suggestions to use NeatUpload code, but that seems to be way too complex to implement and not enough examples are out there

Thus, in the July 2019, what is the most optimal way to implement progress bar in the classic ASP.NET Web Forms applications?

Thank you in advance for all the suggestions/help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer here

[In this ASP.NET forum thread](https://forums.asp.net/t/2157337.aspx)